# How to get Cloudfront subdomain from the request on the custom origin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

How does one get the AWS Cloudfront subdomain from the request on the custom origin that I've created.

The only header that comes close is the Via header but it doesn't contain any useful information

It looks like:

```
Via: 1.1 1026589cc7887e7a0dc7827b4example.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
```

Note that `1026589cc7887e7a0dc7827b4example` is not the original subdomain that I've assigned to the custom origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure CloudFront to through pass Host header to the origin. It is described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html. Note that in this case it will also be included into the CloudFront's cache key, so use it if you plan to serve different content for different values of Host header.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Worked great. We ended up forwarding all headers.

Comment: That might be not the best idea, unless other headers don't change - you will reduce your cache hit rate, as all headers forwarded are automatically included in the cache key